# Targeting cells in a table and then adding data

Tags: jquery, html-table

How do I first target the individual cell of a table with a mouse click, then add my forms data to it.

http://jsbin.com/cazifezaro/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I'm sorry for not formatting on here, every time I try the code becomes formatted oddly.

Comment: Tell me what to do when i click on the td?

Comment: Click on Table Cell, have it be selected, fill in inputs, click add, have data transfer to selected cell

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got it here:

http://jsbin.com/yovigidufo/3/edit

I added a css class to denote the selected cell:

```
td.selected {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Then I changed your javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var toAdd1 = $('input[name=strain]').val();
        var toAdd2 = $('input[name=gen]').val();
        var toAdd3 = $('input[name=veg]').val();
        var toAdd4 = $('input[name=flower]').val();

        $("table.tg tr td.selected").html("<p>"+toAdd1+"</p><p>"+toAdd2+"</p><p>"+toAdd3+"</p><p>"+toAdd4+"</p>");

    });

    $("table.tg tr td").on("click", function() {
        $("table.tg tr td").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
     });
});
```

Edit: You might want to start the page off with one of the cells with the "selected" class already assigned, just so that the user isn't confused about the input. Or you could only enable the inputs if they have a cell selected.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is for personal use, but I will use your suggestion when I open it up!

Comment: That worked for selecting the cells! I will try and modify the code so that it adds, ALL of the data from the input fields.  Thank you for helping me! I may post again if I dont figure it out.

Comment: My mistake, I introduced a bug! I've fixed the code above. It was in the $("#button).click method if you just grab the .html() that will fix it (I also update the jsbin)

Comment: I appreciate the help! The code doesnt seem to be adding all of the inputs values.  Any idea why?

Comment: Is the jsbin working? If the jsbin is working and some local code is not, it may be that you need to recopy the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2gxyqv7/15/)

HTML

```
        <form>
        Strain Name: <input type="text" class="values" name="strain" value="Type your text here!"> <br />
        Generation: <input type="text" class="values" name="gen" value="Type your text here!"><br /> 
        Veg Start: <input type="text" class="values" name="veg" value="Type your text here!">      <br /> 
        Flower Start: <input type="text" class="values" name="flower" value="Type your text here!"><br /> 

        </form>
        <button id="button">Add</button>
        <div id="messages"></div>
        <div id="table1"><table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-hdgz" id="a1">Plant A1</th>
    <th class="tg-hdgz" id="a2">Plant A2</th>
    <th class="tg-hdgz">Plant A3</th>
    <th class="tg-hdgz">Plant A4</th>
    <th class="tg-hdgz">Plant A5</th>
    <th class="tg-hdgz">Plant A6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant B1</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant B2</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant B3</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant B4</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant B5</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant B6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant C1</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant C2</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant C3</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant C4</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant C5</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant C6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant D1</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant D2</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant D3</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant D4</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant D5</td>
    <td class="tg-hdgz">Plant D6</td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#button').click(function() {

        var toAdd1 = $('input[name=strain]').val();
        var toAdd2 = $('input[name=gen]').val();
        var toAdd3 = $('input[name=veg]').val();
        var toAdd4 = $('input[name=flower]').val();
        //Variables for for input data(strain, gen etc..)

        $('.sel').append("<p>"+toAdd1+"</p>","<p>"+toAdd2+"</p>","<p>"+toAdd3+"</p>","<p>"+toAdd4+"</p>");

        // This Allows me to add all the for inputs together.


    });

   $('.tg-hdgz').on('click', function(){

    $('.tg-hdgz').removeClass('sel');
     $(this).addClass('sel');
   });



});
```

CSS code

```
form {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    display: inline-block;
}
#messages {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Garamond, Times, Serif;
}

.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:13px 13px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:13px 13px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
table .sel{font-weight:bold;background-color:#985401 !important;text-align:center}
.tg .tg-hdgz{font-weight:bold;background-color:#036400;text-align:center}
```